# Spam in Notifications

Tags: notification, malware

[image: HA YOUR NAME WAS FISHED]

I'm seeing the following message in my notifications: HA BAШE ИMЯ ПPИШEЛ ФИHAHCOBЬIЙ ПEPEBOД...

Google translate gives this as HA YOUR NAME WAS FISHED...

I can't clear the notification for some reason. But I'm more concerned with how this notification was created in the first place.

I'm doing a search on my system for files containing the text in Russian. What else should I look for to try to get to the bottom of this?

I'm on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: It may be caused by malicious desktop notification from web-browser. Which web-browser do you use ?

Comment: Firefox, mostly.

Comment: It looks like it's coming from the Calendar app. There is an event in one of my linked calendars with that message in it. 

Well. Time to go lock down the associated account...

Comment: OK. Well, it's calendar spam in my gmail account. What a world.

Comment: The Google translation is wrong because of using Latin letters instead of visually similar Cyrillic ones. The text says: A financial transfer has arrived to your name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a spam event in my linked Google account.

I removed Google from my Online Accounts in Settings.